# How to check whether a xml element value is "null" using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

My source XML:

```
<PrtiesData>
         <newParty userId="1234">
             <userData>
                 <item key="FirstName">Grace</item>
                 <item key="LastName">null</item>
            </userData>
        </newParty>
        <newParty userId="5678">
             <userData>
                 <item key="FirstName">Naghia</item>
                 <item key="LastName">null</item>
            </userData>
        </newParty>
</PrtiesData>
```

I am using the below XSL to transform :

```
<xsl:element name="parties">
         <xsl:for-each select="/PrtiesData/newParty/userData" >
             <xsl:variable name="Name" select="concat(../item[@key='FirstName'],'-',../item[@key='LastName'])"/>
                 <party partyId="{$Name}"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:element>
```

The OutputXML which generated using above xsl and input XML:

```
<Parties>
    <party partyId="Grace-null"/>
    <party partyId="Naghia-null"/>
</Parties>
```

How to remove null from partyId ? Here party Id is FirstName+LastName of Item element.

Comment: *"How to remove null from partyId"* You did not clarify what you want instead.

Comment: Null should be ignored. and the expected output  is:
<party partyId="Grace"/>
<party partyId="Naghia"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using XSLT 2.0, you could use `string-join` instead of `concat` here

```
 <xsl:variable name="Name" 
               select="string-join((item[@key='FirstName'], item[@key='LastName'][. != 'null']), '-')"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for such a quick solution.. Its worked for me